# Как сделать тень под страничкой

Tags: html, css

Как с помощью `CSS` и `HTML` сделать тень под страничкой, которая находится на фоне. Или это как-то рисуется, или создаётся полоска и добавляется прозрачность (в таком случаи она будет равномерна и не будет выглядеть естественно)? Как это делается? Спасибо.

Comment: Если кроссбраузерно то дивом с background - png картинка вашей тени.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
.shadow{
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #f0f0f0;  /* Firefox до версии 4.0 */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #f0f0f0; /* Safari и Chrome */
  /* Костыли для IE до версии 9 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(offX=5, offY=5, color=#f0f0f0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(direction=120, color=#f0f0f0, strength=10);
  box-shadow: 5 5 10px #f0f0f0; /* для всех остальных, которые поддерживают CSS3 */
}
```

Этот класс применить к div, для которого нужна тень.